# How to add TinyMCE keyboard shortcut

Tags: tinymce

The most thorough documentation I can find of how to add a new keyboard shortcut to TinyMC is at this page: http://www.lifeinsuranceonmyterms.com/other/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-tinymce-how-to

It involves adding this code to the main TinyMCE source file, tiny_mce_src.js (and then recompressing):

```
t.addShortcut([keyboard command], [shortcut name], [command name]);
```

Is there a way to add a shortcut without hacking the core/TinyMCE?

> Update: Specifically, I want to add shortcuts to apply h2/h3/h4 or other TinyMCE button actions to selected text in TinyMCE.

Answer (score 2):

Last time i added a keybord shortcut it was using jQuery.
take a look at [**jquery.hotkeys**](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) plugin which lets you enable keyboard shortcuts with a simple one liner:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+a', fn);
```

**update**

if you want to check if the TinyMCE editor is active and it has a selected text then here are the functions you need:

```
function isTinyMCEactive(){ //check if editor is active
    is_tinyMCE_active = false;
    if (typeof(tinyMCE) != "undefined") {
        if (tinyMCE.activeEditor == null || tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden() != false) {
            is_tinyMCE_active = true;
        }
    }
    return is_tinyMCE_active;
}

function tinyMCEhotkeys(tag){
    if (isTinyMCEactive()){
        var selected_content = '';
        selected_content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
        if (selected_content != '' || selected_content != null){ //check if editor has selection
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand("mceInsertContent", 0, '<' + tag + '>' + selected_content + '</' + tag + '>');
        }
    }
}
```

now once you have these functions the rest is easy:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+1', tinyMCEhotkeys('h1'));
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+2', tinyMCEhotkeys('h2'));
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+3', tinyMCEhotkeys('h3'));
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+4', tinyMCEhotkeys('h4'));
```

Comment: In this case I'm trying to add a keyboard shortcut specific to TinyMCE. I.e. shortcuts for each header (h1/h2/h3/h4) when text is selected in the TinyMCE editor.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. And figured it out. Hope it still helps (someone) #Threadnecro

in `functions.php` I add a tinyMCE plugin:

```
function mce_button_js( $plugin_array ) {
  $plugin_array['notes'] = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/tinymce.js';
  return $plugin_array;
}
add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'mce_button_js' );
```

the file /js/tinymce.js has:

```
(function() {
  tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.Notes', {
    init: function(ed, url) {
      ed.addButton('code', {
        title: 'Code',
        cmd: 'code'
      });

      // here I add the shortcut.
      ed.addShortcut('ctrl+k', 'description', 'code');
      ed.addCommand('code', function() {
        var selected_text = ed.selection.getContent(),
          $node = jQuery(ed.selection.getStart()),
          return_text = '';

        if (selected_text !== "") {
          return_text = '<code>' + selected_text + '</code>';
        }
        ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, return_text);
      });
    }
  });
  // Register plugin
  tinymce.PluginManager.add('notes', tinymce.plugins.Notes);
})();
```

This adds a code button to the `wysiwyg` editor. And it maps `ctrl+k` as hotkey for that action.

Sources

- [wptuts](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/guide-to-creating-your-own-wordpress-editor-buttons/) Adding the button
- [TinyMCE documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.addShortcut) about adding a shortcut

Comment: do you what is the keyword for enter key? I tried adding ctrl + enter but tinymce won't recognise

Comment: Sorry I don't know the keyword for `enter` I suggest asking that at the TinyMCE community as it's part of tiny MCE. Altough you could try asking it here as a question.