# Create keyboard shortcuts for HTML mode

Tags: html-editor

I always use the HTML editor for writing all my post.

So I always have manually typed all the tags such as "`<strong></strong>`" for bold... "`<i></i>"` for italics etc.

I don't want to use the Visual Mode, as I use many plugins for which I have to type in shortcodes and many other personal reasons for using HTML mode only.

I was wondering if I can create shortcuts for all the operation (in HTML editor) which otherwise are present in the Visual Mode.

Comment: What you actually looking for is a way to easily insert shortcodes when in html mode?

Comment: yes... exactly I want to define my shortcuts for both shortcodes and other normal html tags, can we do that in wordpress ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. There ***are*** buttons for 'bold', 'italic', and a dozen or so more in the HTML editor.

Comment: ya, there are.. what I want to setup is keyboard shortcuts for those buttons.. is this possible ?

Comment: For regular definitions there are keyboard shortcodes.Just like word  -  ctrl +b = BOLD, ctrl + u = UNDERLINE etc... for your shorcodes you need a select menu..

Comment: Sorry... misread. Those keyboard shortcuts are created by "/wp-includes/js/tinymce/tinymce.js". You can look in there for a sample of how to do it.

Comment: @SagiveSEO, in FireFox (at least) those keyboard shortcuts don't work in the HTML editor. `ctrl+b` opens the bookmarks sidebar, for example. The visual editor used Javascript to override that.

Comment: thats not true mate... you need to highlight the word / sentance you wish to make bold / underline / italic... i just checked it using firefox. in anycase i have found this answer (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33444/how-to-add-tinymce-keyboard-shortcut) which deals with this question... hope this helps. Again... i use this shortocdes ctrl + 1, ctrl + b ETC without adding nothing to my code in multiple sites with ease

Comment: ctrl + u opens the source code view in firefox. ctrl + b te favorite view and so on.

Comment: You would have to do this using javascript, there are several jQuery hotkey things around.

Answer (score 3):

It needs a bit of javascript to do that. You need a listener and some actions. Here we go...

At first enqueueing the javascript to the post and post new screens:

*PHP:*

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'keyboradshortcuts4htmleditor', 10, 0 );

function keyboradshortcuts4htmleditor(){

    add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'keyboradshortcuts4htmleditor_enqueue_javascript', 10, 0 );
    add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post.php', 'keyboradshortcuts4htmleditor_enqueue_javascript', 10, 0 );

}

function keyboradshortcuts4htmleditor_enqueue_javascript(){

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'keyboradshortcuts4htmleditor',
        plugins_url( 'keyboradshortcuts4htmleditor.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'jquery', 'keyboradshortcuts4htmleditor_selection' ),
        false,
        true
    );

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'keyboradshortcuts4htmleditor_selection',
        plugins_url( 'selection.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'jquery' ),
        false,
        true
    );

}
```

The second javascript is a small snippet to get the selected text from the textarea. No more words about it.

That was quite simple. Now the difficult part. We need a javascript which listen to the keyboard and do some actions on a specific keypress. This should only happend when a key **inside** the textarea (editor) is pressed. We use jQuerys `.keypress()` method and bind it to the textarea (id '#content' ): `jQuery( '#content' ).keypress( ... )`
Now we have to check if a specific key was pressed and trigger that action. I use a simple array as keymap (keycode -> function to do) and call the function with `eval()`.

In your actions you have to check if a text is selected or not and deal with it. **The following script is a rough draft**! You have to understand what happend there and define our own shortcuts. The script have to be refacotred, I am not a javascript expert.

*JavaScript:*

```
/*
 * KeyBoardShortCuts4HTMLEditor
 *
 * @author: Ralf Albert
 *
 */
( function( ) {

    keymap = null;

    KeyBoardShortCuts4HTMLEditor = {

            textarea_id: 'content',

            tags_open: [],

            init: function(){

                kbsc = this;

                kbsc.keymap = kbsc.initKeymap();

                jQuery( '#' + kbsc.textarea_id ).keypress(

                    function( event ){

                          var key = event.which;

                        // debugging & Development
                        //console.log( 'Keypress: ' + key );

                        if( 'undefined' !== kbsc.keymap[key] ){
                            callFunction = kbsc.keymap[key];
                        }

                        try{

                            eval( 'kbsc.' + callFunction + '();' );

                        } catch (e) {} finally {};

                    }

                );


            },

            initKeymap: function(){

                var keymap = [];

                keymap[63] = 'help';
                keymap[66]  = 'bold';
                keymap[73]  = 'italic';

                return keymap;

            },

            insertAtCaret: function( text ){

                Selector.insertAtCaret( kbsc.textarea_id, text );

                return;

            },

            openCloseTags: function( selected, tag ){

                if( undefined === selected.lenght ) {

                    if( undefined === kbsc.tags_open[tag.id] || null === kbsc.tags_open[tag.id] ){

                        kbsc.tags_open[tag.id] = true;
                        kbsc.insertAtCaret( tag.open );

                    } else {

                        kbsc.tags_open[tag.id] = null;
                        kbsc.insertAtCaret( tag.close );

                    }


                    return true;
                }

                return false;

            },

            help: function(){

                var helpstr = '';

                for( var i in kbsc.keymap ){
                    var key = String.fromCharCode(i);
                    helpstr = helpstr + key + ': ' + kbsc.keymap[i] + '\n';
                }

                alert( helpstr );

                return;

            },

            bold: function (){

                var tag = {
                        id: 'bold',
                        open: '<b>',
                        close: '</b>'
                    };

                var selected = Selector.getSelection( kbsc.textarea_id );

                if( undefined === selected.length || 0 === selected.length ) {

                    kbsc.openCloseTags(
                            selected,
                            tag
                    );

                } else {

                    Selector.replaceSelection( kbsc.textarea_id, tag.open + selected.text + tag.close );
                }

            },

            italic: function(){

                var tag = {
                        id: 'italic',
                        open: '<i>',
                        close: '</i>'
                    };

                var selected = Selector.getSelection( kbsc.textarea_id );


                if( undefined === selected.length || 0 === selected.length ) {

                    kbsc.openCloseTags(
                            selected,
                            tag
                    );

                } else {

                    Selector.replaceSelection( kbsc.textarea_id, tag.open + selected.text + tag.close );
                }

            }


    };

    KeyBoardShortCuts4HTMLEditor.init();

} )( jQuery );
```

You can found the complete files [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/4184652).